# Cannot get the same instance of a scoped component - Dagger 2 Clean architecture

Tags: android, dependency-injection, scope, dagger-2, clean-architecture

I'm using Dagger 2 in  clean architecture project, I have 2 fragments. These 2 fragments should be scoped together to share the same instances, but unfortunately, I got empty object in the second fragment. 
**Application Component**

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = [ContextModule::class, RetrofitModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent {
    fun exposeRetrofit(): Retrofit
    fun exposeContext(): Context
```

}

Data layer - Repository

```
class MoviesParsableImpl @Inject constructor(var moviesLocalResult: MoviesLocalResult): MoviesParsable {
private val TAG = javaClass.simpleName
private val fileUtils = FileUtils()
override fun parseMovies() {
    Log.d(TAG,"current thread is ".plus(Thread.currentThread().name))
    val gson = Gson()
    val fileName = "movies.json"
    val jsonAsString = MyApplication.appContext.assets.open(fileName).bufferedReader().use{
        it.readText()
    }
    val listType: Type = object : TypeToken<MoviesLocalResult>() {}.type
    moviesLocalResult  = gson.fromJson(jsonAsString,listType)
    Log.d(TAG,"result size ".plus(moviesLocalResult.movies?.size))
}

override fun getParsedMovies(): Results<MoviesLocalResult> {
    return Results.Success(moviesLocalResult)
}
}
```

**Repo Module**

```
    @Module
interface RepoModule {
    @DataComponentScope
    @Binds
    fun bindsMoviesParsable(moviesParsableImpl: MoviesParsableImpl): MoviesParsable
}
```

**MoviesLocalResultsModule(the result need its instance across different fragments)**

```
    @Module
class MoviesLocalResultModule {
    @DataComponentScope
    @Provides
    fun provideMovieLocalResults(): MoviesLocalResult{
        return MoviesLocalResult()
    }
}
```

**Use case**

```
class AllMoviesUseCase @Inject constructor(private val moviesParsable: MoviesParsable){
fun parseMovies(){
    moviesParsable.parseMovies()
}

fun getMovies(): Results<MoviesLocalResult> {
    return moviesParsable.getParsedMovies()
}
```

}

**Presentation Component**

```
    @PresentationScope
@Component(modules = [ViewModelFactoryModule::class],dependencies = [DataComponent::class])
interface PresentationComponent {

    fun exposeViewModel(): ViewModelFactory

}
```

First ViewModel, where I got the result to be shared with the other fragment when needed

```
class AllMoviesViewModel @Inject constructor(private val useCase: AllMoviesUseCase):ViewModel() {
    private val moviesMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<Results<MoviesLocalResult>>()
    init {
        moviesMutableLiveData.postValue(Results.Loading())
    }
    fun parseJson(){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default){
            useCase.parseMovies()
            moviesMutableLiveData.postValue(useCase.getMovies())
        }
    }

    fun readMovies(): LiveData<Results<MoviesLocalResult>> {
        return  moviesMutableLiveData
    }
}
```

Second ViewModel where no need to request data again as it's expected to be scoped

```
class MovieDetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(private val useCase: AllMoviesUseCase): ViewModel() {

    var readMovies = liveData(Dispatchers.IO){
        emit(Results.Loading())
        val result = useCase.getMovies()
        emit(result)
    }
}
```

First Fragment, where data should be requested:

```
class AllMoviesFragment : Fragment() {
    private val TAG = javaClass.simpleName
    private lateinit var viewModel: AllMoviesViewModel
    private lateinit var adapter: AllMoviesAdapter
    private lateinit var layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager
    private var ascendingOrder = true

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        DaggerAllMoviesComponent.builder()
            .presentationComponent(
                DaggerPresentationComponent.builder()
                    .dataComponent(
                        DaggerDataComponent.builder()
                            .applicationComponent(MyApplication.applicationComponent).build()
                    )
                    .build()
            ).build()inject(this)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(AllMoviesViewModel::class.java)
        startMoviesParsing()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_movies, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setupRecyclerView()
        viewModel.readMovies().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            if (it != null) {
                when (it) {
                    is Loading -> {
                        showResults(false)
                    }

                    is Success -> {
                        showResults(true)
                        Log.d(TAG, "Data observed ".plus(it.data))
                        addMoviesList(it.data)

                    }

                    is Error -> {
                        moviesList.snack(getString(R.string.error_fetch_movies))
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Second Fragment, where I expect to get the same instance request in First Fragment as they are scoped.

```
class MovieDetailsFragment: Fragment() {
    val TAG = javaClass.simpleName
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory
    lateinit var viewModel: MovieDetailsViewModel
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val depend = DaggerAllMoviesComponent.builder()
            .presentationComponent(
                DaggerPresentationComponent.builder()
                    .dataComponent(
                        DaggerDataComponent.builder()
                            .applicationComponent(MyApplication.applicationComponent).build())
                    .build()
            ).build()

        depend.inject(this)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(MovieDetailsViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        viewModel.readMovies.observe(this, Observer {
            if (it!=null){
                Log.d(TAG,"Movies returned successfully")
            }
        })
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scopes tell a component to cache the results of a binding.  It has nothing to do with caching instances of any components.  As such, you are always creating a new `DataComponent`, `PresentationComponent`, and `AllMoviesComponent` in your fragments' `onCreate` methods.

In order to reuse the same `AllMoviesComponent` instance, you need to store it somewhere.  Where you store it can depend on your app architecture, but some options include `MyApplication` itself, the hosting `Activity`, or in your navigation graph somehow.

---

Even after fixing this, you can't guarantee that `parseMovies` has already been called.  The Android system could kill your app at any time, including when `MoviesDetailFragment` is the current fragment.  If that happens and the user navigates back to your app later, any active fragments will be recreated, and you'll still get null.